# Default argument initializer: Local variable error in clang but not msvc

Tags: c++, default-value

In Visual Studio 2022 the code below compiles fine with the MSVC compiler selected but gives the indicated error with the clang compiler selected.  My understanding is that a local variable is one whose defining declaration is inside a function.  Could someone please clarify?

```
"...default argument references local variable 'bar' of enclosing function"

int bar = 5, x = bar;
int main()
{
   extern int bar;
   int Test(int foo = bar);
}
```

Comment: This is a non-standard extension of the MSVC compiler, however, the clang compiler which is based on the LLVM project does not support this feature.

Comment: Why do you need to declare a function inside a function like this, especially with a strange `extern` default?

Comment: I don't "need" to do this.  It is just some test code I tried.  I guess part of my question is if bar is simultaneously both a local and a global variable.

Comment: A variable can't be local AND global. In fact you should avoid global variables as much as you can anyway.

Comment: What I mean by avoid global variables : If you need shared data between pieces of your program then you need dependency injection e.g. create a struct to hold your data (or better an interface with getters to your data) and inject that into pieces of code that need that data. Doing this will make unit testing possible and maintenance in the future much more easy.

Comment: The comments are deviating from my initial issue.  I'm well aware of the pitfalls of global variables and I am familiar with getters, setters, and all that.  None of that pertains to my original issue.  Because the defining declaration of bar is not inside the function and because bar can be accessed by other files in the project, bar is a global (external) variable.  It is also the same variable as the one declared as extern inside main, which I verified by setting a breakpoint and seeing that its value is 5.  However, clang is calling it a local variable.  Why?  How can it be both?

Comment: `bar` is local since it's declared in a block scope. Your local declaration shadows the outer declaration. (Also, the defining declaration is not `extern`, which is wrong.)

Comment: You are correct about the defining declaration not being the one declared with the explicit extern, which is what I said.  The defining declaration is the one that's outside the function and it has external linkage and can link to other files.  The extern storage class is indicated on the one declared inside the function so it will link with the one declared outside rather than creating a new variable that's unrelated to the one that's outside.  Am I wrong about that?

Answer (score -2):

found intresting behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int bar = 5, x = 6;

int Test2(int i = bar)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    {
        int Test2(int foo=x);
        Test2(); // prints 6
    }
    Test2(); // prints 5
}
```

The output is

```
6
5
```

I am using UCRT64 from MSYS to compile.

Using default params, is **dangerous**. And, somebody may able to override default function param value by redefining function in its scope.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the danger of default params has nothing to do with my original issue.  My concern is why clang is calling a global (external) variable a local variable.